# Could add data SSRS with power bi

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am trying to get data from dataset by working on SQL Server Mobile Report publisher .. after clicking on dataset and choose dataset i receive an error ..

[image1 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsYCT.png)

What i tried is :
Whereas i already created and save dataset by working on Microsoft Report Builder. ..
So after that when i open SQL Server Report Publisher and choose dataset then i face the error ..

please help me out

thanks